# I am looking for a generic and fast strategy to predict the outcome of a query?

Tags: sql, h2

I am looking for a generic and fast strategy to predict the outcome of a query. Queries can be complex, and the table can be huge, resulting in long execution times and very large result sets. I am looking for a generic approach to predict the number of records in the result set so I can warn the user

tried this with the LIMIT parameter, it still takes a lot of time

Comment: That's what the concept of "estimated cost" of execution plans come into play. H2, unfortunately, does not provide it. Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server engines do.